# In javascript, filter and map an array in one function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In Javascript, Array.filter() takes an array and filters it down based on a certain criteria.

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4,5].filter(el => el > 3);
console.log(a);
```

Result: `[4,5]`

Array.map() takes an array and returns a new array of equal length, usually mutating the original's elements in the process.

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4].map(el => el + 10);
console.log(a);
```

Result: `[11,12,13,14,15]`

My question is, besides combining the two functions like this:

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5].filter(el => el > 3).map(el => el + 10);
console.log(a);
```

is there an efficient way to filter and mutating an array, that doesn't involve multiple lines of code like most `Array.forEach`, `for`, and `for..in` routines? I know that `Array.filter().map()` is pretty efficient, I'm just wondering if it can be further streamlined.

Comment: Use a reduce function.

Comment: Unless there is a measurable reason to seek an optimization `filter().map()` is good — it's very readable and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.reduce` to take care of filtering and mapping all at once.

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5].reduce((arr, el) => el > 3 ? arr.concat(el + 10) : arr, []);
console.log(a);
```

You could also make your own `mapIf` polyfill function.

```js
// Reduce Only
if (Array.prototype.mapIf === undefined) {
  Array.prototype.mapIf = function(predicateFn, applyFn) {
    return this.reduce((ref, el) => predicateFn(el) ? ref.concat(applyFn(el)) : ref, []);
  };
}

// Filter + Map
if (Array.prototype.mapIf === undefined) {
  Array.prototype.mapIf = function(predicateFn, applyFn) {
    return this.filter(predicateFn).map(applyFn);
  };
}


let a = [1,2,3,4,5].mapIf(el => el > 3, el => el + 10);
console.log(a);
```